# retrieve turtlebot orientation

Tags: ros, yaw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everybody,

kindly help me out to retrieve exact turtlebot's orientation.
i have used yaw to determine the orientation but when the robot move the yaw become inaccurate.
the yaw command the i used is as follows:

```
   yaw=atan2(2*(x*y+w*z), w*w + x*x - y*y - z*z);
```

kindly,give me an advice on how to retrieve the exact turtlebot's orientation.
thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127766/retrieve-turtlebot-orientation/) by [nadal11](https://answers.ros.org/users/7216/nadal11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're getting Odometry msgs, you can use the function tf::getYaw with the odometry msg directly to get the yaw.

documentation is here: http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a33e93f413622e296d0a2a93b252bbb4b

```
tf::getYaw(odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation)
```

---

Originally posted by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) with karma: 380 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nadal11](https://answers.ros.org/users/7216/nadal11/) on 2014-05-14**:
thanks mate. I have sort this thing out actually. the one you suggest give the same output as the one i suggested.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have figure the answer for this problem.
the yaw can be retrieved from turtlebot using this equation:

```
yaw=atan2(2*orientation.w*orientation.z), orientation.w*orientation.w - orientation.z*orientation.z);
```

thank you to everybody.

---

Originally posted by [nadal11](https://answers.ros.org/users/7216/nadal11/) with karma: 23 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1